# Continuity in dual space with weak$^*$- topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$,$Y$ be locally convex topological vector spaces. Assume now I have an operator $T:Y'\rightarrow X'$ where $Y'$ and $X'$ are equipped with the weak$^*$-topology.

Does this imply that $T$ is continuous, iff for every sequence $f_n,f \subset Y'$ such that $f_n(y) \rightarrow f(y)$ for every $y \in Y$ we have $ T(f_n)(x) \rightarrow T(f)(x)$ for every $x \in X$?

This seems natural, but I don't know why this sequential continuity is sufficient for continuity in the weak$^*$-topology?

Comment: As you wrote, this is just the sequential continuity of $T$. Do you have any reason to believe that this implies continuity?